# Weird git error: failed to run prune

Tags: git

I've had a corrupt git repo, which I apparently managed to restore (by rsyncing `.git/objects` from the remote), since I got down to this:

```
$ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (7628/7628), done.
dangling blob ac27b1087864e0b313fed793521090cfc03c82cb
dangling blob 22aae8babcc61b3048557531c1550cb4fe33de93
dangling blob 62bd6159a9e19187a778c0ae5e7ef4f0b227197b
```

The dangling blobs at this point are seemingly these:

```
$ tree -p .git/objects/
.git/objects/
├── [drwxrwsr-x]  22
│   └── [-r--r--r--]  aae8babcc61b3048557531c1550cb4fe33de93
├── [drwxrwsr-x]  62
│   └── [-r--r--r--]  bd6159a9e19187a778c0ae5e7ef4f0b227197b
├── [drwxrwsr-x]  ac
│   └── [-r--r--r--]  27b1087864e0b313fed793521090cfc03c82cb
├── [drwxrwsrwt]  info
│   └── [-rw-rw-r--]  packs
└── [drwxrwsrwt]  pack
    ├── [-r--r--r--]  pack-65f501f2463a843b574db1ac1bde89b44e9acf38.idx
    └── [-r--r--r--]  pack-65f501f2463a843b574db1ac1bde89b44e9acf38.pack

5 directories, 6 files
```

However, when I try `git gc --prune=today`, I get this:

```
$ git gc --prune=today
Counting objects: 7628, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1993/1993), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7628/7628), done.
Total 7628 (delta 5234), reused 7628 (delta 5234)
usage: git prune [-n] [-v] [--expire <time>] [--] [<head>...]

    -n, --dry-run         do not remove, show only
    -v, --verbose         report pruned objects
    --progress            show progress
    --expire <expiry date>
                          expire objects older than <time>

error: failed to run prune
```

It's as if `git gc ...` called `git prune` with a syntax error ?! EDIT: note that `git gc` without further arguments succeeds without a problem...

Is there a quick way to get `git gc --prune=today` to succeed in this repo? The local `git` version is:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.1
```

---

EDIT: I removed the dangling blob files:

```
$ rm -rf .git/objects/{22,62,ac}
```

... and I got to this:

```
$ git gc
Counting objects: 7628, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1993/1993), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7628/7628), done.
Total 7628 (delta 5234), reused 7628 (delta 5234)

$ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (7628/7628), done.
```

... but `git gc --prune=today` still fails in the same way. Is it because it finds no object files to "prune"?

Comment: `git gc` invokes multiple commands and apparently when it invokes `git prune` it is doing so incorrectly, somehow.  You could set `GIT_TRACE=1` in the environment to see just how `git gc` invokes `git prune` here. I don't know of any specific bugs in it, but git 1.9.1 is pretty old now.

Answer (score 0):

Fix : run `git gc --prune=now`

---

`git prune` understands `--expire now` but not `--expire today`.

Which is a bit odd since `git prune` understands `yesterday`, and `0 day ago` (which acts as `now`).

This question is old, one improvement has been brought to the error message.
As of version 2.18 (released in june 2018) :

> **Git 2.18 Release Notes**
>
> [...]
>
> - "git gc --prune=nonsense" spent long time repacking and then
>     silently failed when underlying "git prune --expire=nonsense"
>     failed to parse its command line.  This has been corrected.

Error message now looks like :

```
$ git gc --prune=today
fatal: failed to parse prune expiry value today
```